# Trying to access ng-repeat elements while the elements are not rendered yet

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wavesurfer.js

I'm going to use WaveSurfer library for creating a playlist. Consider each element of ng-repeat is a wavesurfer element. Here is what I'm doing:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="wave{{item.id}}" wavsurfer></div>
</div>
```

Here is the angular directive which I'm using to convert each div element to a wavesurfer element:

```
app.directive('wavsurfer', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // load wav file
        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#'+attrs.id,
          waveColor: 'red',
          progressColor: 'purple'
        });

        wavesurfer.load(FileUrl);

    }
};});
```

But I'm getting below error coz the element is not rendered yet in ng-repeat:

```
Error: Container element not found
```

Could you please let me know what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: try `container: document.querySelector('#'+attrs.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please refer following code :

It seems issue is that before your ng-repeat finishes; wavesurfer tries to load its plugin.
Refer following directive code :

```
.directive('wavsurfer', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var wavesurfer
      console.log(attrs.id)
      $timeout(function() {
        wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#' + attrs.id,
          waveColor: 'red',
          progressColor: 'purple'
        });
          wavesurfer.load('http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');
      }, 1000)
    }
  };
});
```

working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4564/)

Also adding snippet here

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
  }, {
    id: 2,
  }, {
    id: 3,
  }, {
    id: 4,
  }];
}]).directive('wavsurfer', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var wavesurfer;
      console.log(attrs.id)
      $timeout(function() {
        wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#' + attrs.id,
          waveColor: 'red',
          progressColor: 'purple'
        });
        wavesurfer.load('//ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');
      }, 1000)

    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.4.0/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TreeController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="wave{{item.id}}" wavsurfer></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's embarrassing but I don't have enough reputation to upvote otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: @ImanNorouzi least u can accept this as answer surely to close this thread, so if anyone else faces this issue can refer to this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="items.length" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="wave{{item.id}}" wavsurfer></div>
</div>
```

ng-if will render the ng-repeat divs after collecting the items array.